# display array of different objects c# (class inheritance)

Tags: c#, class, object, inheritance

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm new to inheritance (only had 1 lecture on it so far) and would appreciate any help here. I've been given this problem and think I have it nearly done. Make a Book class, add two child classes. display all. Plus other stuff but that's the core problem.

When I try to display each object and it's info in a for loop i cant figure out how to access the BookGrade of a TextBook. I have made an array of Books and put everything in there. I know this isn't right but i don't know where to go from here. I have tried making an array of TextBooks  like this

```
TextBook[] bookArray = new TextBook[3] { Book1, TBook1, CBook1};
```

But then i need to add a cast to Book1, which works, but i still cant implicitly convert type 'CoffeeTableBook' to 'TextBook'. I get this, but don't know how to get around it. I get this error "'Book' does not contain a definition for 'BookGrade'.."

I have 3 classes, Book, TextBook and CoffeeTableBook. Both TextBook and CoffeeTableBook classes are derived from the Book class.

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookDemo
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Book
        Book Book1 = new Book();
        Book1.BookNum = 123456;
        Book1.BookTitle = "Harry Potter 1";
        Book1.BookAuthor = "JK Rowling";
        Book1.BookPrice = 5.95;

        //Text Book
        TextBook TBook1 = new TextBook();
        TBook1.BookNum = 123436;
        TBook1.BookTitle = "Harry Potter 2";
        TBook1.BookAuthor = "JK Rowling";
        TBook1.BookPrice = 5.95;
        TBook1.BookGrade = "A";


        //Coffee Table Book
        CoffeeTableBook CBook1 = new CoffeeTableBook();
        CBook1.BookNum = 123136;
        CBook1.BookTitle = "Harry Potter 7";
        CBook1.BookAuthor = "JK Rowling";
        CBook1.BookPrice = 95.95;

        Book[] bookArray = new Book[3] { Book1, TBook1, CBook1 };


        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bookArray[i].GetType() == typeof(TextBook))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", bookArray[i].BookNum, bookArray[i].BookTitle, bookArray[i].BookAuthor, bookArray[i].BookPrice, bookArray[i].BookGrade);//'Book' does not contain a defination for 'BookGrade'..
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", bookArray[i].BookNum, bookArray[i].BookTitle, bookArray[i].BookAuthor, bookArray[i].BookPrice, "N/A");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
class Book
{
public int BookNum { get; set; }
public string BookTitle { get; set; }
public string BookAuthor { get; set; }
public double BookPrice { get; set; }

}

class TextBook : Book // must be priced between $20.00 and $80.00
{
const double MIN_PRICE = 20;
const double MAX_PRICE = 80;
public string BookGrade { get; set; }

new public double BookPrice
{
    set
    {
        if (value < MIN_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
        }
        else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
        }
        else
        {
            base.BookPrice = value;
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return base.BookPrice;
    }
}
}

class CoffeeTableBook : Book //must be priced between $35.00 and $100.00
{
const double MIN_PRICE = 35;
const double MAX_PRICE = 100;
new public double BookPrice
{
    set
    {
        if (value < MIN_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
        }
        else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
        }
        else
        {
            base.BookPrice = value;
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return base.BookPrice;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to the specific type Textbook in your if (bookArray[i].GetType() == typeof(TextBook))-Branch

eg.:

```
if (bookArray[i].GetType() == typeof(TextBook))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", bookArray[i].BookNum, bookArray[i].BookTitle, bookArray[i].BookAuthor, bookArray[i].BookPrice, ((TextBook)bookArray[i]).BookGrade); // Works now, because we view bookArray[i] as TextBook and not it's underlaying type
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", bookArray[i].BookNum, bookArray[i].BookTitle, bookArray[i].BookAuthor, bookArray[i].BookPrice, "N/A");
}
```

I'd usually suggest using the new Switch-Capabilities (patterns) described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), but I don't want to interfer with your teacher.

Comment: I had tried
    (TextBook)bookArray[i].BookGrade
and not
    ((TextBook)bookArray[i]).BookGrade)
cheers

Comment: That would change the type of BookGrade instead of bookArray[i] :)

Answer (score 1):

In alternative you can redefine your classes and avoid checking the type in the for:

```
class Book
{
public int BookNum { get; set; }
public string BookTitle { get; set; }
public string BookAuthor { get; set; }
public double BookPrice { get; set; }
public string BookGrade = "N/A";

}

class TextBook : Book // must be priced between $20.00 and $80.00
{
const double MIN_PRICE = 20;
const double MAX_PRICE = 80;
public string BookGrade { get; set; }

new public double BookPrice
{
    set
    {
        if (value < MIN_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
        }
        else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
        }
        else
        {
            base.BookPrice = value;
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return base.BookPrice;
    }
}
}

class CoffeeTableBook : Book //must be priced between $35.00 and $100.00
{
const double MIN_PRICE = 35;
const double MAX_PRICE = 100;
new public double BookPrice
{
    set
    {
        if (value < MIN_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
        }
        else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
        {
            base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
        }
        else
        {
            base.BookPrice = value;
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return base.BookPrice;
    }
}
}
```

and in the main:

```
foreach (Book singleBook in BookArray)
        {

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", singleBook.BookNum, singleBook.BookTitle, singleBook.BookAuthor, singleBook.BookPrice, singleBook.BookGrade);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override 'toString()' method to set exact way of displaying your object

```
class Program
{
    class Book
    {
        public int BookNum { get; set; }
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
        public string BookAuthor { get; set; }
        public double BookPrice { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() //!
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", this.BookNum, this.BookTitle, this.BookAuthor, this.BookPrice);
        }
    }

    class TextBook : Book // must be priced between $20.00 and $80.00
    {
        const double MIN_PRICE = 20;
        const double MAX_PRICE = 80;
        public string BookGrade { get; set; }

        new public double BookPrice
        {
            set
            {
                if (value < MIN_PRICE)
                {
                    base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
                }
                else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
                {
                    base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.BookPrice = value;
                }
            }
            get { return base.BookPrice; }
        }

        public override string ToString() //!
        {
            return base.ToString() + " " + this.BookGrade;
        }
    }

    class CoffeeTableBook : Book //must be priced between $35.00 and $100.00
    {
        const double MIN_PRICE = 35;
        const double MAX_PRICE = 100;

        new public double BookPrice
        {
            set
            {
                if (value < MIN_PRICE)
                {
                    base.BookPrice = MIN_PRICE;
                }
                else if (value > MAX_PRICE)
                {
                    base.BookPrice = MAX_PRICE;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.BookPrice = value;
                }
            }
            get { return base.BookPrice; }
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Book
        var book1 = new Book
        {
            BookNum = 123456,
            BookTitle = "Harry Potter 1",
            BookAuthor = "JK Rowling",
            BookPrice = 5.95
        };

        //Text Book
        var TBook1 = new TextBook
        {
            BookNum = 123436,
            BookTitle = "Harry Potter 2",
            BookAuthor = "JK Rowling",
            BookPrice = 5.95,
            BookGrade = "A"
        };


        //Coffee Table Book
        var CBook1 = new CoffeeTableBook
        {
            BookNum = 123136,
            BookTitle = "Harry Potter 7",
            BookAuthor = "JK Rowling",
            BookPrice = 95.95
        };

        var bookArray = new Book[] {book1, TBook1, CBook1};


        foreach (Book t in bookArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t); //! i.e Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your for loop in a shorter format as:

```
string output;

foreach (Book bk in bookArray)
{
    output = string.Format(
                 "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
                 bk.BookNum,
                 bk.BookTitle,
                 bk.BookAuthor,
                 bk.BookPrice,
                 (bk is TextBook)
                     ? (bk as TextBook).BookGrade
                     : "N/A");

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine what happens if you add more classes derived from `Book`, your code will end up getting unwieldy

```
if(book.GetType() == typeof(TextBook))
{
}
if(book.GetType() == typeof(CoffeeTableBook))
{
}
if(book.GetType() == typeof(AnotherBookType))
{
}
if(book.GetType() == typeof(MagicalSpellsBook))
{
}
if(book.GetType() == typeof(Whatever))
{
}
```

And it gets even worse if the code to actually display the `Book`s gets into play.

What can you do to solve the issue? First of all introduce a `BookRenderer`

```
class BookRenderer
{
    List<ISpecificBookRenderer> specificBookRenderers = ...; // pass via constructor

    public void RenderBook(Book b)
    {
        var matchingRenderer = specificBookRenderers.First(r => r.BookType == b.GetType());
        matchingRenderer.RenderBook(b);
    }
}
```

Types derived from `ISpecificBookRenderer` are responsible for rendering your books. The interface `ISpecificBookRenderer` is defined as

```
interface ISpecificBookRenderer 
{
    Type BookType { get; }

    void RenderBook(Book b);
}
```

Now you can create a renderer for each type derived from `Book`, e.g.

```
class TextBookRenderer
{
    public Type BookType => typeof(TextBook);

    public void RenderBook(Book b)
    {
        if(b is TextBoox textBook)
        {
            // output TextBook value
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Passed book is not a TextBook", nameof(b));
    }
}
```

Of course this comes at costs, but the single classes stay neat and clean. Additionally it's conceivable to need to render your books to a different system. Introducing these renderers allows you to swap implementations, without changing the actual classes. **And** you don't mix up business logic (your `Book` classes - and they are in this case, because they perform the price checks) with presentation, which you would do, if you simply overrode `ToString` to achieve your desired presentation.